# Where does console output go

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to debug a Python script by placing a `print("foo=" + foo)` statement in my code.

But where does the output appear?

It doesn't appear on the Python Console, and it doesn't appear on the area that appears when you drag the lower edge of the infobar downwards (what is the name for this area? My script errors show up in red here.)

Comment: I believe that area is called the info panel, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Info Editor (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface#Overview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view python error messages?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It's printed to the system console. If it's not opened, go to *Window > Toggle System Console*.

Note that this option is only available on Windows. On other OS, start Blender from a terminal.

See here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/introduction.html

You may also use this script:
[Is there anyway to make blender print errors in the UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5394/is-there-anyway-to-make-blender-print-errors-in-the-ui)

Comment: ah man, you have even written a script to fix it. One upvote is not enough!

Comment: Window > Toggle System Console doesn't exist in Blender 2.77

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it clearly exists on Windows in Blender 2.77: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NTFd8.png - are you on another OS by any chance? Read the answer again in that case, you need to start Blender in a shell.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 and blender 2.7.6, window > Toggle System console also doesn't exist

Comment: @user824624: read again, I clearly stated that this option is exclusively available on Windows. On Linux and OS X, you need to start Blender from a shell.

Comment: On OS X you can run it from terminal like this: **/Users/eugenekulabuhov/Downloads/blender-2.77-OSX_10.6-x86_64/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender**
Update the path to blender.app.

Comment: Warning! If you open the Console, don't ever close it! It will kill Blender instantly without saving!

Comment: Of course you can close it. Go back to main Blender window and hit the same hotkey (or same menu item) that opened it. You must mean don't hit the close application button on the upper right. Just like you wouldn't hit that button in the main Blender window. :)

Comment: Open Finder; Go to Apps; Right click on **Blender.app**; _Open Terminal in this folder_; run `./Contents/MacOS/Blender` from Terminal

Answer (score 22):

**Here is my script which redirects the print() function to all open python console windows.**

```
import bpy
def print(data):
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'CONSOLE':
                override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
                bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(override, text=str(data), type="OUTPUT")
```

Comment: Helpful to make `data` parameter `*data` - and `text` parameter to  `text=str(" ".join([str(x) for x in data]))` (This allows print to take multiple parameters)

Comment: @Brad or similarly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93728/blender-script-run-print-to-console

Comment: FANTASTIC! Not sure why that isn't a default operation or why there isn't a simple bpy command to do that already. But thank you so much!

Answer (score 10):

With my own experience and help from [Sambler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23310144/5673677) I made a simple app for the purpose of opening Blender with terminal.

[Download the application](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3phj2-3Wce6cVE2ODNYOHdBMkE/view?usp=sharing)

How to use it:

1. Navigate yourself to `blender.app` with finder.

[image]

2. Right click on Blender and select *Show Package contents*.

[image]

3. [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3phj2-3Wce6cVE2ODNYOHdBMkE/view?usp=sharing) the app and unzip it.

[image]

4. Drag the app into Blender's `Contents` folder.

[image]

5. Drag the app to dock and open for the first time.

[image]

Alternatively here is the applescript source: (currently, with plenty of helpful comments)

```
set myPath to ((path to current application) as string) --find the path to blenderOpen.app
set myPath to ((characters 1 through ((length of myPath) - 1) of myPath) as string) --rip off the last ":"
set charDelete to (last character of myPath) -- rip off the "blenderOpen.app"
repeat until charDelete = ":" -- rip off the "blenderOpen.app"
    set myPath to ((characters 1 through ((length of myPath) - 1) of myPath) as string) -- rip off the "blenderOpen.app"
    set charDelete to (last character of myPath) -- rip off the "blenderOpen.app"
end repeat
set myPath to myPath & "MacOS" --find the blender runtime by appending this path

set myPath to quoted form of the POSIX path of myPath -- convert path so terminal understands
(*
why this little if statement down below?
This if statement is here because if a user
opens terminal and runs some command,
then afterwards runs our script,
we want to use a new window so as not
to interfere with the user.
However, if WE open terminal,
than we want to use the window 
that terminal just made for us.
*)

if testterminal() then
    tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd " & myPath & " && ./blender" -- tell terminal to open new window, and open blender, Voila!!!
else
    tell application "Terminal" to tell front window to do script "cd " & myPath & " && ./blender" -- tell terminal to open blender, in the current window, Voila!!!
end if


return myPath
on testterminal()
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains "Terminal"
end testterminal
```

This app also enables you to open up as many instances of blender as you want at the same time.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers, kindly link to the other post/answer and if you could tidy this up that would be great, thanks!

Comment: @iKIsR And how would that be done, do you think i should just delete all in edit and paste a link, i'm sorry about the duplicates, how should i go about tidying this up? and thanks for commenting.

Comment: For one, if you are new to markdown, there is a styleguide help button to the top right of the editing area when you are creating the post. You have some comments about leaving an image once you have the rep (which you now do) so maybe add those. Basically look at any post from a high rep user and try to structure it like that. We prefer self contained answers so links to external sources can be added but it's helpful if that same content is summarized here.

Answer (score 9):

If you're on macOS and in a terminal, locate `blender.app`, then do:

> `./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender`

Blender's log messages will now appear in the terminal window from which you started it.

Note that `open blender.app` does *not* show you any log messages.

Answer (score 6):

I'm currently using Blender 2.78 and I think that the easiest way to see your console logs is to go inside the blender container, exactly like in previous posts. Then go to MacOs folder and run blender script. [image]
It will open terminal and blender application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Updated with the second part to the solution.

When you click "run script," Python errors are reported in the console.  Blender API errors, however, are not.  If you have Blender API errors before the line where your call to print() happens, then your code never reaches that line.  Blender and Python both quietly let this happen without error or warning.

Tick the "register" box in the text editor, save, and click "run script".  Your script class should have a bl_label field set to a string.  Go to the viewport, press spacebar, and type that string.  When it shows up in the results, click it.

Now your Blender API errors will show themselves.  Correct your code, and when your print() call is reached, it will print to the *system* console.

I'm shocked that this doesn't seem to appear anywhere on threads about this yet, especially since differences between types such as BMesh and Mesh render show-stopping API errors like this *really* easy to make.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Blender from Linux and didn't start it in the shell (which is fine to do), then you can usually tail this log file to see the stdout output from Blender (and any other GUI program)

```
tail -f ~/.xsession-errors
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way in Ubuntu Linux is to create a Desktop launcher.
Simply right click on desktop, popup menu offers create launcher option. Select.
When creating the launcher, you get the option to run in Terminal. Select that option.
Now every time you launch Blender from the desktop, it automatically runs the terminal.

Comment: Window manager is...?

Answer (score 0):

I often need to patch @TheMindVirus's print method, so here is my variant.

```
print_orig = print
def print(*data):
    if len(data) == 1: data = data[0]
    print_orig(data)
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'CONSOLE':
                override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
                for line in str(data).splitlines():
                    bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(override, text=line.rstrip(), type="OUTPUT")
```

- handles inputs of type other than string
- handles multi-line string prints
- prints to both terminal/console and blender console, for easy multi-use

I also advise combining this print function, with a top-level try catch, which lets the blender console print many runtime errors for devel which normally would only print to the terminal

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        raise
```