# Why my blender user preferences input panel is blank?

Tags: customization

Can't figure it out why my blender user preferences input panel is blank? I use macbook pro?

[image: Blank Add-ons panel.]

Comment: Have you tried loading the factory defaults?

Comment: If there are error messages in the [system console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go) could you paste them.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting them to factory defualts:

> 1) To reset interface AND the current opened file: File > Load Factory
>   Settings;
>   2) To open a file without loading its interface: File>
>   Open, then untick the "Load UI" in the left of the File Browser
>   window.
>
> Ctrl+U saves the current file as Blender default file (the one seen
>   when Blender is opened).
>
> Seen at:
>   http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?t=202110&page=1

Or try updating your version of blender by installing the most recent version:

> http://www.blender.org/download/

Hope that helps! :)