# How to view python error messages?

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial and I can´t go forward and finish the tutorial. My problem is that when i click on run script it gives me a problem saying "Python script fail, look in the console for now..."

I use the recent blender and blender 2.69 and both of them give an error.

[image]

The problem is in the top red line. The tutorial I'm following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jipaKhQWDeg Can't pass from the 15:00 minute.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows you can toggle the console windows using the *Menu: Window / Toggle System Console*

[image]

[Documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Console_window)

Comment: Oh, it was referring to the **System** console, not the **Python** console. I guess that makes sense, though the error message is a bit confusing.

Comment: lmao I feel stupid, been wondering about this forever...

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the python console open to see the real python error. On Windows the console window opens separately when Blender launches. On OSX and Linux, you need to launch the blender.app file from the Terminal to have access to the separate python console window.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if this answer isn't quite to your question, but having to do with the subject:

If you are on a mac, here is something for you:

with my own "getting annoyed" experience and help from the idea of [this guy (sambler)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23310144/5673677) I made a simple app for the purpose of opening blender with terminal.

**---Please try it, it is easy to install and super handy---**

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3phj2-3Wce6cVE2ODNYOHdBMkE/view?usp=sharing) is the application.
This is how you use it:

1. Navigate yourself to blender.app with finder.
2. Right click on blender and select "Show Package contents".
3. Download the app using the link above and unzip it.
4. Drag the app into blender's "Contents" folder.
5. Drag the app to dock and open for the first time.
6. (optional) Dance around the room and sing about how fortunate you are to have such an app.

please visit [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58473/27816) for source code and an image guide.

Comment: Just open a Terminal window and type /Applications/Blender/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender and hit return