# Rigify Incorrect Bone Configuration for rig type. Incorrect armature

Tags: rigging, rigify, error

Complete NUBE here. I'm a college student. This is my final project. I'm trying to animate my robot. When I click "generate" to create my rig, using rigify, I get a message, close but not verbatim, to this: "Rigify Incorrect Bone Configuration for rig type. Incorrect armature." I have no idea what to do. I've tried everything I can find online.

In addition, I've seen people copied and pasted their error messages. How do they do that? Mine just flash across the top of the interface and then they are gone in a second. Weird.

I would attach my file but I don't see an option for that.

Comment: Any help is welcome. Even if you can tell me how to copy my error message.

Comment: Pull down the top header you will (probably) see the error message. If not open the [console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46903/2217), and copy it from there.