# How to edit Quick Tools Addon and create your own menu (with some basic python scripting question)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

first, sorry for my english, :D i want to ask quite a lot about editing and inserting correct script/operator for adding menu/operator for editing quick tools addon..

so, i've edited quick tools by jonathan williamson to fit my needs. but years passed and i forgot how to edit addon correctly, test it, and inserting the menu that i need and never finished editing it.

here's what my version of quick tools look like

[image]

so, i want to add autosmooth and its angles value under shade flat operator, but it seems that i couldn't get that working properly. here's my attempt to add the autosmooth operator..

[image]

but i just couldn't make it work, it says python fails, look for console..

and here's, my question is,

1. how to edit and inserting a menu/operator correctly? it seems that if i copy its python path, it gets me nowhere, only some path that actually working.. but operator like "autosmooth"can't work at all. is there any special things that i need to consider before adding them blindly by just copy its path guys?
2. how to safely edit and test the addon that we create/edit? as far as i remember, i pressed some button to make it run, and after i edit them, it ruins everything.. and my addon can''t work or at least after i installed them, it just can't run or listed in addon tab..
3. if i want to make menu/operator, "add subsurf with 2 subdivs and optimal display", "delete subsurf", "display subsurf in edit mode", "display "subsurf cage", how to to that and create a proper menu in quick tools?
4. and the last one, if i want to create menu , ädd bevel with angle method", ""bevel modifier width" and "bevel modifier segment" how to create that guys?

that's all my question guys, sorry if i disturbing you with this long question.. i really hope to be able understand python scripting so that i can make my overall work faster..

best regards

Comment: This site requires one question per post, please split them.

Comment: [*"but i just couldn't make it work, it says python fails, look for console"*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages)

Comment: layout.prop(context.object.data, 'use_auto_smooth')