# How can I reset the cursor in the UV Editor with Python?

Tags: python, uv-image-editor

Observing the manual informs that it is possible to reset the projection but could not reset the position of the cursor in the UV Map.

bpy.ops.uv.cursor_set(location=(0.0, 0.0))

Location, Cursor location in normalized (0.0-1.0) coordinates

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.uv.html

Comment: Are you looking for python solution or is this question about how to do it with UI?

Comment: Script (Python).

Comment: So are you not able to use bpy.ops.uv.cursor_set()?

Comment: Blender informs that I should view the console.

Comment: Most likely you have a poll error. You cannot run uv operators directly from the text editor or python console. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to adjust cursor from another context with the following snippet:

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.active_object
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':   #find the UVeditor
        cursor = area.spaces.active.cursor_location   # get cursor location
        area.spaces.active.cursor_location.x = 0.5*1024;
        area.spaces.active.cursor_location.y = 0.5*1024;
```

Because you want to normalize in the (0.0,1.0) interval you will have to actually multiply this with the texture size (in my example hardcoded 1024 number).

Comment: Similarly for the `'UV_EDITOR'` the cursor coordinates are in uv.