# Why are my classes and functions not working in Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting

The buttons I created stopped working, they worked in blender 2.79. By the way, the standard buttons work, but my not. Any thoughts on this? Please tell me what could be the reason. Thank!

Button example:

```
class ALLSELECTDELETE_PT_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
"""All select and delete"""
bl_label = "Delete all"
bl_idname = "object.all_select_delete"
bl_description = "All select and delete"

def execute(self, context):

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Look in system console for errors**

Start blender from a system console and note any error or warning messages that pop up during registration.

[Where does console output go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go)

[How to view python error messages?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages)

Blender 2.8 has a far stricter naming convention for operators and panels.  The operator with `bl_idname = foo.bar` should be given the class name `FOO_OT_bar`  (`_OT_` indicates "Operator Type")

Here is an adjustment to the code, I have prepended the button to the 3DView header to test.

[image]

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_all_select_delete(bpy.types.Operator):
    """All select and delete"""
    bl_label = "Delete all"
    bl_idname = "object.all_select_delete"
    bl_description = "All select and delete"

    def execute(self, context):

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()

def draw_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("object.all_select_delete")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_all_select_delete)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.prepend(draw_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I have the __init__.py file and the allselectdelete.py file with this button, and for some reason __init__.py stopped calling the button, although everything is fine in 2.79 blender. Maybe something has changed with the import?

Comment: There are other files, with standard buttons interleaved with mine, standard ones are imported, but mine aren’t

Comment: All there is to go on is the code you posted in question. Demonstrated that after some minor adjustments the button renders fine  in the 2.8 UI.  Suggest pasting pertinent code in question, and / or a link to your full code.  Start blender from a system console and note any error or warning messages that pop up during registration.

Comment: It could for instance be  broken `poll` methods.

Comment: For some reason, the blender 2.8 does not see my buttons, this error was detected in the console

C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\********\__init__.py:124
rna_uiItemO: operator missing srna 'bones.wings_enable'

Comment: Since it appears both the code is secret, and its name `scripts\addons********_init_.py`  is secret I cannot help further.

Comment: The name of the addon is classified, I don’t want to advertise it