# How to get a 2D silhouette of a 3D mesh in Blender 2.8?

Tags: mesh, scripting, nurbs-surface, shrinkwrap

I would like to just take a 2D silhouette outline of a side of one of my 3D meshes. I located the question [How to extract side-view outline (e.g. top view) of a 3D object to 2D surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121119/83776) but since it was made over a year ago, and I am using Blender 2.8, the script does not work for me. Any advice on how to update it? It seems to error out around this part:

```
copy = ob.copy()
sil = bpy.data.meshes.new("silhouette")
copy.data = sil
scene.objects.link(copy)
scene.objects.active = copy
copy.select = True
bm.to_mesh(sil)
```

Also, more importantly, how would I export the silhouette? Like it wouldn't save as an stl file.

Comment: ... and what is the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'link'

Comment: It would be best for others reading, if you edit your question to include that error message.

Comment: The answer is in the duplicate, it is a side-effect of Collections being added to blender at the scene level.  I'll let you digest and post the answer yourself as I hope you'll find that more satisfying.

Comment: @Forrest  Edited original.  When you get the 15 or whatever rep required to comment feel free to comment on answers re updates.  Welcome to bse.  Re error messages https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages