# Python- Adding menu button to add duplicate of active object at 3D cursor

Tags: python, scripting

I'm attempting to learn Python, and figured the easiest way to learn would be by studying code snippets, and expanding from there. So to start with, I want to slightly modify the "ui_panel_simple" template so that instead of adding a primitive object at the 3D cursor, it will add a duplicate of the active object at the 3D cursor.

The full code is as follows:

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Add object duplicate"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Add duplicate", icon='OBJECT_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If I change `row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")` to `row.operator(bpy.ops.object.duplicate()`, then I lose the newly added button in the custom panel. I can freely change 'cube" to any primitive object and all works as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For UI layout `layout.operator` you only need the names after bpy.ops, in your case

```
        row.operator("object.duplicate")
```

Always check the [system console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go/6174#6174) for error messages if something isn't working

```
row.operator(bpy.ops.object.duplicate())
```

will write to system console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Text", line 32, in draw
 File "/home/batfinger/src/BlenderGIT/qtcreator_build/bin/2.77/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
 ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.object.duplicate" error, can't modify blend data in this state (drawing/rendering)
```

If you don't want the panel to show when there is no active_object add a poll method

```
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
```

or not as the operator will display as disabled when there is no active object.