# Problems installing an addon

Tags: python, add-on, command-line

I'm trying to install an addon called Panorama-Tracker, here's the link to it: https://github.com/dfelinto/Panorama-Tracker 
The author mentioned that commands should be pasted in a terminal before installing the addon, I copied the commands, run Text Editor in Blender, pasted the commands and hit Run Script, I got an error of check Console, checking the console I saw nothing. I'm sure I'm doing it the wrong way, is there a possibility someone can show me how to do it right?

[image]

Comment: That is the text editor (lhs of image).  You want to open a terminal of your operating system .  Which OS are you on? This is the console to check for errors too, ie the system console  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go/6174#6174 not the python console (on rhs of image)

Comment: no need to use git to clone the repo , You can simply download those 6 .py files with your browser , zip them and install that zip as an addon.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, I just tried Window > toggle system console, I have the command prompt open, then what, I'm sorry but my level in programming and coding is 1/100

Comment: I just tried that, I'm getting (failed to get addon path) error. @root

Comment: @Georges , I tried and it works for me, i downloaded the files in a folder , and zipped the folder , not the files. [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G4C9l.png)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works finally, please put this as an answer, I don't know why the author made it to be so complicated when it can be very simple. @root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender expects addons to be a zipped directory of python scripts.
if somehow installing an addon gives the error `failed to get addon path` , investigate the addon and make sure it has the following structure.

```
addon.zip
   |
   |--directory_name/
          |
          |--__init__.py
          |--script.py
          |--script2.py
          |--etc...
```