# Blender script won't run "Python script fail look in the console now"

Tags: python, scripting

I run 2.78 blender version and have this error says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Scene'
```

script below:

```
import bpy
from bpy import Scene, Text3d, Window

helloText = Text3d.new("Hello World")
helloText.setText("Hello World!")

scn = Scene.GetCurrent()
ob = scn.objects.new(helloText)

Window.RedrawAll()
```

Comment: I can't see your error message, you only posted your script. Please edito you question and provide the missing info.

Comment: I put all info that I know, also blender fails to run others script

Comment: I don't really know much about bpy but do know Python. Line 5 looks quite suspect; should it be "hello.setText(...)" instead of "hello = setText(...)"?

Comment: I still get error message  in 2nd line

Comment: Please post the error.
View the consule under the menu "Window" -> "Toggle System Console"  then https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx?mfr=true (minus #1)

Comment: Run blender from through the terminal, run the script, and post the error it gives you.  We can't tell you what is wrong if we have no way of finding out.

Comment: You shouldn't need the second line anyway since the first line already imports the whole of the bpy package so Scene, Text3d and Window should be already imported.

Comment: C'mon guys, (s)he posted the script, and from that it's darn easy to determine the error message... it appears to be a 2.49 or prior script with `Blender` replaced by `bpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using the old [2.49 (and prior) API](https://www.blender.org/api/249PythonDoc/) `bpy` is far different from the old `Blender`

Here is one way to add a hello world text object using the [new API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/).

```
import bpy

from bpy import context

scene = context.scene
# add a new font curve and set text
font3d = bpy.data.curves.new("Text", 'FONT')
font3d.body = "Hello World"
# add a new text object
text3d = bpy.data.objects.new("Text", font3d)

# link it to the scene
scene.objects.link(text3d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, when Blender says "look in the console now", you should look in the console window...

The ["console window"](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Console_window) here is not your text editor, and also not the "Python Console", but a separate window, see this question: [Where does console output go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go)