# How to Interrupt a process the results in an unresponsive interface (like "Control-C")

Tags: interface

I imagine that this question has been asked, but I could not find the answer, so I'll ask it:

I just created an icosphere and tried to increase the number of subdivisions to 5. But, whoops, I entered 25! Now Blender is churning away on a difficult task that I would rather not be completed. Is there anyway to "Undo" a process while Blender is still "thinking about it"? Like a "Control-C" equivalent? Or, do I just need to kill the whole Blender application?

Comment: *Some* of the complex procedures like unwrap of super-high-poly can be interrupted by Ctrl+C if you open Blender from console or [toggle its console window](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go). However this doesn't work on your exact case; the problem is unresponsive interface during the operation. Afaik it wasn't changed yet.

Comment: Called learning the hard way... "don't do it again" lol.  @MrZak have a feeling Ctrl-C only works as a keyboard interrupt (from console) on a script.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ESC</kbd> key might do it.  When the task is going to take an age, you can go to Windows' Task Manager and stop the Blender program outright...(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>)  It does mean you lose what you've been doing since the last save however.

Comment: Yeah, I have currently just been just force quitting Blender. Typically, I do something like this when I have not saved my work in a long time, so I was hoping there would be some smart way to avoid quitting Blender.

Comment: That's on my wish list also :)