# is there any way to turn on the auto smooth in blender startup files

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, interface, pynodes

[image]

Hi, I need help is there any way I can turn on the auto smooth by default turn on the time blender startup files. if add anything to the screen that time also wants the object must have an auto smooth turn on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done easily, could be implemented with Python though, check this [Is it possible to have Smooth Shading on by default?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128296/is-it-possible-to-have-smooth-shading-on-by-default).

Also, something that might help, if you hold *ALT* when clicking the *Auto Smooth* option (or any other option in *Properties* tab) it will be applied to **every** selected object in your scene.

Comment: Thanks man for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

It's a per-object setting, not a scene setting. You can enable it for the objects present by default in your startup file, but you will have to enable it as well for any other object you create afterward.

However, you can do it quickly in object mode by selecting a bunch of mesh objects and <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Shade Autosmooth.