# Using script for select only flat or smooth objects

Tags: python, scripting

I can't find any python commands allowing to select only flat objects in my scene.
I make a script for select all flat object, smooth then, and apply a auto smooth 30°.
For the rest I can do it, but any idea for select by type object (flat/smooth) ?
Thx community !

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91685/using-python-to-set-object-shading-to-smooth  None, All or Any face of a mesh can be set to smooth shading.

Comment: No it's in object mode, if statut smooth / flat shading have maybe a boolean type for info.