# How can I get all materials which are using an ambient occlusion node?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, ambient-occlusion

I'd like to get all materials using an ambient occlusion (AO) node and return their names in the console:

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.data.materials
for mat in mat:
    mat_name = (mat.name)
    ntree = mat.node_tree
    node = ntree.nodes.get("Ambient Occlusion", None)

    if node is not None:
        print("Material With Ambient Occlusion:", mat_name)
```

It works fine for the start up file, but when I run it in another scene I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodes'

What is wrong? And why does the code only work for the start up file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all materials have an associated `node_tree`. This is only present where the 'use_nodes' checkbox has been used as this creates the node tree.

Your problem is that one or more material does not have a `node_tree`. The solution is to include a test before the `ntree.nodes.get()` to first check that there is actually an attribute 'nodes' - and to simply skip that material if none is found:

```
import bpy

# Run through all materials of the current blend file
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    # If the material has a node tree
    if mat.node_tree:
        # Run through all nodes
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            # If the node type is Ambient Occlusion 
            if node.type == 'AMBIENT_OCCLUSION':
                # Print the name of the material
                print("Ambient Occlusion Node found in:", mat.name)
```

Comment: Thanks to @brockmann for the great edit to improve clarity.

Comment: Thank you!it's fixed!