# Renaming a Properties with Drivers

Tags: rigging, properties

So I have an issue with renaming Custom properties that are being used in a driver. As an example, I made a custom property for some drivers. But when I renamed the properties, the drivers associated with the properties just stopped working, and I need to manually change the data path of each driver. Is there a way to change the property's name without needing to manually change each data path? Meaning that each driver that has the properties data path will rename itself.

I also have some concerns if this issue also happened when I renamed other things such as bones. How do I rename it without breaking all the drivers I made?

Comment: Scripting would work, but might take some work to be automatic. Sounds like a decent rightclickselect.com feature request.

Comment: Can it be assumed that the usage of the prop in the driver is as a SINGLE PROPERTY type variable target, with data_path set to eg `["prop"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rename all single prop variable targets using custom prop.**

Code slapped together from [How to find out what is using an image in a blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230383/how-to-find-out-what-is-using-an-image-in-a-blend-file)

Searches thru every driver in the blend file and renames "oldname" to "newname"

Test script below, with example call renaming and single property driver variables targets from `["prop"]` to `["length"]`  Edit last line to suit.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import bpy_prop_collection

    
def rename(oldname, newname):
    
    def rename(col):
        for o in col:
            ad = getattr(o, "animation_data", None)
            if not ad:
                continue
            for d in ad.drivers:
                for v in d.driver.variables:
                    if (
                        v.type == 'SINGLE_PROP'
                        and v.targets[0].data_path == f'["{oldname}"]' ):
                            
                        v.targets[0].data_path = f'["{newname}"]'
    while next(filter(None, (
        rename(getattr(bpy.data, p)) 
        for p in  dir(bpy.data) 
        if isinstance(
                getattr(bpy.data, p, None), 
                bpy_prop_collection
                )                
        )
        ), None):
            continue
      
x = rename("prop", "length")
```

PS excuse round about way of the script, a better logic would be to return the object, driver, target tuples of matches.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.