# How to find the users of a material?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, blend-files

There are a few materials in a blend file I have that I don't think are necessary in the file. However, none of these materials show up in orphan data. I know something is using these materials because if I add the material to another object, it will show a 2 in the material slot (for those who don't know, this means that 2 items are using the material. One of these is the object I plugged it into and the other one is what I want to figure out.) I checked all the meshes in the file and couldn't find a single one that was using the materials I think are not needed. None of these materials have any fake users either. How can I find what is using the material so I can be sure that I can delete it?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the file, but a material can be referenced in several places, for instance in the render passes override or in geometry nodes

Comment: To be sure it is not assigned to anything: if you're choosing a material slot on an object and use the dropdown menu to assign a material, is the one in question there marked with a 0 in front of the name? If not, then it's assigned to something, whatever that might be (as @Gorgious pointed out, it's not necessarily a mesh object).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann There is no 0 in front of the material

Comment: Then it's most likely assigned to something...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann How can I figure out what it is? I checked all the meshes and couldn't find any that were using the material.

Comment: I would try to find it in the _Outliner_ under a _Display Mode_ like _Data API_ maybe... expand all hierarchy and try to filter with the name... but I don't know. Hard to tell without the original file what to look for. Maybe it's completely easy to find with the correct intention. Without the file I can only give you tell you to look everywhere.

Answer (score 10):

This appears to be the same question as [How to find out what is using an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230383/how-to-find-out-what-is-using-an-image-in-a-blend-file/) except that it's for materials rather than images. The first answer there, in the form of a python script, will solve this as well; by replacing the image bits with material bits.

Copy and paste script block into text editor and run it. Output written to [system console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go):

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import bpy_prop_collection

def search(ID):
    def users(col):
        ret =  tuple(repr(o) for o in col if o.user_of_id(ID))
        return ret if ret else None
    return filter(None, (
        users(getattr(bpy.data, p)) 
        for p in  dir(bpy.data) 
        if isinstance(
                getattr(bpy.data, p, None), 
                bpy_prop_collection
                )                
        )
        )
        
# report all materials and their users in the console
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    print (20*"-")
    print(repr(mat))
    print("Users:", mat.users)         
    for users in search(mat):
        print(users)
```

Console output (default scene):

```
--------------------
bpy.data.materials['Dots Stroke']
Users: 2
("bpy.data.brushes['Airbrush']", "bpy.data.brushes['Pencil Soft']")
--------------------
bpy.data.materials['Material']
Users: 1
("bpy.data.meshes['Cube']",)
```

Credit goes to [@batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger), see [How to find out what is using an image in a blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230425/31447)

Comment: @brockman deserves half the bounty for updating the python to use mat.*

Comment: No problem, was dead easy to adapt it.

Comment: lol, thought this was the question I answered. Cheers for the cite. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Any idea how to adapt this to search for actions assigned to an armature even if they aren't the current linked action? I've created 8 actions on one rig and I want to return all those action names as a list.

Comment: No luck with bpy.context.active_object.user_of_id(bpy.data.actions['Mixamo_MocapGuy_Idle Neutral 1']). It also only works for linked actions.

Comment: Is this impossible because blender shares data blocks by default? So after unlinking an action it has no metadata that says it was created on a specific rig?