# Appending one object adds an extra object that shares a material

Tags: append

When appending an object into a fresh scene, a second object is also appended.

I have a master asset scene with many objects that use a small number of master materials eg: "Metal MAT", "Concrete Mat". The assets use unique versions of these materials eg: "Fence Metal MAT", "Wall Concrete MAT".
Included in the scene are small planes with the master materials assigned to them respectively.

I appended those small planes with the master materials into a fresh scene so I could mark them as assets for Blender 3.0's asset browser. When doing this all but one object/plane appended correctly.

The "Plastic Bag MAT" (a master material) is assigned to one of the small planes as well as a garbage bag object. When I append the plane into a fresh scene the garbage bag object also gets appended.

What is it about this particular material that is causing this issue?

The plastic bag material is a simple Principled BSDF with noise nodes for the bump.
[image]

When appending the plane, both the plane and bag get added, which are two separate objects. There are no constraints or parenting...I tried to delete the plane, then add a new plane and assigned the material, however it does not fix it, only removing the material stops the issue.

[image]

Comment: Sharing a material shouldn't cause this, but other things such as parenting or object constraints will.

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Linking /  appending brings along users. Script in answer here for FIOP https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230425/15543 or a copy of it as  used in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231277/15543 will list the users of an ID block.  Running on your asset blend file may shed some light.