# Python Math Functions Fail In Blender

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics

My problem is this: I try and run the script in Blender's text editor and the script fails to math functions, cos() does not work.
[image: Failing script within text editor]

When I run the same code in Blender's Python console my pasting it directly, there is no problem
[image: Same code successfully run by pasting into Python console]
What is the reason / how to get it work from the Text Editor?

Comment: You need to either use the math namespace because you've imported it eg `math.cos(angle)` or to use directly, `from math import cos`.  For convenience sake the math and mathutils methods have been imported for you in the console. `from math import *` (See banner message).

Comment: [Always check the system console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go) for errors. _NameError: name 'cos' is not defined_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by @batFINGER in [a comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94247/python-math-functions-fail-in-blender#comment166512_94247): You need to either use the math namespace because you've imported it eg `math.cos(angle)` or to use directly, `from math import cos`. For convenience sake the math and mathutils methods have been imported for you in the console. `from math import *` (See banner message).

Comment: The information in the answers turned out to be useful. I could deduce the syntax at least for the math functions I needed. Now the script works technically. Only thing left is to make it work logically :)

Comment: Then at least upvote it and accept it as answer.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Answer accepted with pleasure.