# How to use Blender to capture handmotion with a hand glove using flex sensor

Tags: python, animation

I am doing a project that using a hand glove with flex sensor and I have to capture the hand motion of fingers and wrist.

I don't know how to connect arduino with Blender, so I searched that we have to use pyserial code for Blender. Then, I wonder how can we change from arduino code to blender code for connecting them together? And How to apply the code for the motion ?

This is the file of the hand that i downloads from Github for this kind of project. They have code already! 
[image]

Comment: Even am doing a similar project, i have corrected some of my errors but i always get caught at the "main_arm = source['Armature']" which says armature not defined even though i have labelled them.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/109672/599