# Display full error at the bottom right of blender 2.8

Tags: interface, error, command-line

I am using a python addon throwing an exception and i can't figure out how to display the full error in blender 2.8+ :[image: error at the bottom right of the ui in red]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tab <kbd>window</kbd> and got to <kbd>toggle system console</kbd>

[image: console]

Comment: Worth noting that the _toggle system console_ menu item is only available on MS windows OS.

Comment: Yes, button is not available on linux. Yet it works if i run blender from terminal but it's annoying.

Comment: let me install linux, I just acquired this pc and t I have not had time to install my linux slackware, as soon as I do I will put the images and tomorrow I will put the command line to bring up the blender console window

Comment: in the terminal that you start blender checks if it is showing the data of the toggle system console, as far as I remember, it must be because it is in blender 2.7xxx which is what I use normally

Comment: Yes it does, but it's boring to launch blender with the terminal:
https://imgur.com/iyqGf37

Comment: what distribution of linux do you use ?

Comment: I like using the linux terminal as a console more than the blender console itself.