# Script for loop issue

Tags: python, command-line, text-editor

So I should be missing something simple. (Amateur here...) I am testing snippets of code to create an addon.

The idea is to create markers on the timeline from a list.

The code below works in the python console but not in the text editor

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
for j in range(len(markerLIST)):
    scene.timeline_markers.new(markerLIST[j], frame=j)
```

Can someone explain to me why that is? And how it fix it?

Thanks

Comment: If you read the python console start message you will notice that some modules and some variables have been imported for our convenience.  eg `bpy` and `C = bpy.context`.  You need to include your imports in the text editor.  Too see errors https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go

Comment: also consider using  `for j, name in enumerate(markerlist):` to enumerate without using range and length methods.  And using `scene = bpy.context.scene` will use the current (context) scene no matter its name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I look for the module that corresponds to the markers

Comment: scene = bpy.data.scenes doesn't work without the ['Scene']. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I am missing where you got the idea to use  `scene = bpy.data.scenes`   I suggested `bpy.context.scene`

Comment: Oh... yes. ok. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the python console start message you will notice that some modules and some variables are builtin or have been imported for our convenience. eg `bpy` and `C = bpy.context`.

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 19:16:38)  [GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]

Command History:     Up/Down Arrow
Cursor:              Left/Right Home/End
Remove:              Backspace/Delete
Execute:             Enter
Autocomplete:        Ctrl-Space
Zoom:                Ctrl +/-, Ctrl-Wheel
Builtin Modules:     bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports: from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data
```

You need to include your imports in the text editor. To see errors [Where does console output go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go)

also consider using for `j, name in enumerate(markerlist):` to enumerate without using range and length methods. And using `scene = bpy.context.scene` will use the current (context) scene no matter its name.

```
import bpy # NEED THIS

scene = bpy.context.scene # < the context scene

markerLIST = ["foo", "bar"]

for j, name in enumerate(markerLIST):
    scene.timeline_markers.new(name, frame=j)
```

Consider giving the list both the name and frame

```
import bpy # NEED THIS

scene = bpy.context.scene # < the context scene

markerLIST = [(1, "foo"),
              (20, "bar"),
        ]

for j, name in markerLIST:
    scene.timeline_markers.new(name, frame=j)
```