# All Imports Wont Show

Tags: import

[image: ![After Importing .svg file]

Any files I try to import don't show up, like at all. I've tried zooming in, I've tried opening different types of files as well, same problem. ( Blender Ver 2.79 )

Comment: The scene is empty.  Check console for errors.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go?noredirect=1&lq=1