# Why does clearing the rotation of a bone do it in steps instead of all at once?

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

I have a problem resetting to default pose, When I click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> it will rotate it back to the default position in steps or if I hold it. I have also noticed when I'm twisting the hand it will twist around super fast.

[The File](https://www.sendspace.com/file/oihzms)

Getting this error in the console

Dependency cycle detected:

OBArmature/Upper arm.L/POSE_IK_SOLVER() depends on

OBArmature/Arm Pull ik.L/BONE_DONE() via 'IK'

OBArmature/Arm Pull ik.L/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'

OBArmature/Arm Pull ik.L/BONE_POSE_PARENT() via 'Pose -> Ready'

OBArmature/Arm Bender Controller.L/BONE_DONE() via 'Parent Bone -> Child Bone'

OBArmature/Arm Bender Controller.L/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'

OBArmature/Arm Bender Controller.L/BONE_CONSTRAINTS() via 'Constraints ->Ready'

OBArmature/Upper arm.L/BONE_DONE() via 'Copy Location'

OBArmature/Upper arm.L/POSE_IK_SOLVER() via 'IK Solver Result'

Dependency cycle detected:

OBArmature/Upper Leg.L/POSE_IK_SOLVER() depends on

OBArmature/Leg pull ik.L/BONE_DONE() via 'IK'

OBArmature/Leg pull ik.L/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'

OBArmature/Leg pull ik.L/BONE_POSE_PARENT() via 'Pose -> Ready'

OBArmature/Leg Bender Controller.L/BONE_DONE() via 'Parent Bone -> Child Bone'

OBArmature/Leg Bender Controller.L/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'

OBArmature/Leg Bender Controller.L/BONE_CONSTRAINTS() via 'Constraints ->Ready'

OBArmature/Upper Leg.L/BONE_DONE() via 'Copy Location'

OBArmature/Upper Leg.L/POSE_IK_SOLVER() via 'IK Solver Result'

Detected 2 dependency cycles

Comment: I would guess you have a dependency cycle. Have a look in the [system console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go) for error messages.

Comment: I have looked at the console now, thank you for that by the way. Iv un-parented the ik controller from the end of the arm bone and it's fixed my original problem but it still says it has a cycle error for the arm, I'm also getting one for the leg but I haven't experienced any problems there so Im still a little lost.