# addon lily surface scrapper problem

Tags: texturing

I have been trying to use the addon lily surface scraper and for some reason it does not upload some of my texture URLs, and I keep getting a error.

I get this error using CCO textures

[image]

and this error using cg book case textures
[image]

for some reason texture haven is working fine.
does anyone have a idea for why this is happening and BTW I am on blender version 2.91

Comment: Please add a link to the addon page.   Can copy error message from system console and paste as text, much easier to read.  What url have you copied to clipboard?

Comment: You? https://github.com/eliemichel/LilySurfaceScraper/issues/134  The addons maintainer has replied and asked for same.

Comment: give me one minute

Comment: i dont know how to copy error message from system console

Comment: https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures/black-tiles-06

Comment: https://cc0textures.com/view?id=Wood047

Comment: i tries some other textures they dont seem to work either

Comment: from the same websites

Comment: Re system console: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go  If that is your issue on github page recommend replying there.

Comment: ok i will reply on the github but what should i do with the link on the last comment?

Comment: The link answers how to see system console. Select and copy error message text from there.  If it is you that brought up the issue here https://github.com/eliemichel/LilySurfaceScraper/issues/134  add the details there.

Comment: ok thank you for the help