# I cant export to .fxb

Tags: export

i've been working on this map for a game for a while and now i'm tryng to export it so i can use it in unity. however everytime i try to export to fxb i get this error.[image]

i've aplied all my transforms and modifiers but the issue persists. i've tried to figure out if it was one object that was causing all the problems, and it is caused by specific object but by quite a few of them and i cant just leave all of them out... does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: Divide and conquer: select half of them and try, then the other half, then half of the half the fails. etc.

Comment: Error messages are also printed to system console, from which can be copied as text and pasted here as text. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go

Comment: about batFINGER's comment: copied error messages are searchable, images not

Comment: i was able to trace it back to a specific set of benches, my guess is i maybe accidentaly used smart uv project or something similar on these. after unwrapping them using box projection the model exports!

Comment: @MartienRurenga if you found a soulution please write it as an answer and not as a comment.