# Create a lot of spheres with xyz coordinates and radius

Tags: scripting, csv

How can I create a lot of spheres? I have a csv file with x,y,z,r (radius) coordinates. I saw some topics but nothing worked to me.

I tried ask a question, but this was classified as "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." I read some topics but nothing worked to me, so that I opened a new topic.

I have this code:

```
import bpy

text_file = open("C:\\Users\\nabuc\\Desktop\\1700txt - copia.txt", "r")
lines = []

#Read in contents to a list
for line in text_file:
    lines.append(line.strip())

#create spheres
for e in lines:
temp=e.split(',')
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments = 64, ring_count = 32, location=(float(temp[0]),float(temp[1]),float(temp[2])),size = float(temp[3]))
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
text_file.close()
```

but:

Python:   File "C:\Users\nabuc\Documents\untitled.blend\Text", line 12
temp=e.split(',')
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

location: :-1

thanks for your help

EDIT 2 (I can't edit code on answer)
To avoid this indentation error, I edit as:

```
import bpy

text_file = open("C:\\Users\\nabuc\\Desktop\\1700txt - copia.txt", "r")
lines = []

#Read in contents to a list
for line in text_file:
    lines.append(line.strip())

#create spheres
for e in lines:
    temp=e.split(',')
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments = 64, ring_count = 32, location=(float(temp[0]),float(temp[1]),float(temp[2])),size =         float(temp[3]))
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
    text_file.close()
```

but this return:

Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: looks like you are a pretty beginner ;) you should have written that. First...python needs the right indentation to work. This is what the error says. Since you didn't even format your code right here, we cannot say what's wrong because you just copied/paste your code here without thinking. To make your question to something we can work with you have to do: copy your code in the question, then select the code and then tap this button (brackets)[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JomVW.png  so that your code gets formatted. But maybe you should think about posting your blend file...

Comment: @Andre welcome to BSE. We like to help.  However it is outside the scope of the site to teach python to, or help each individual fix their  basic python syntax or  runtime  errors.  Suggest looking into getting a text editor that highlights python syntax errors (like basic indent as above)  Search using the error message online eg _`"IndentationError: expected an indented block"`_   To view a specific error https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend you watching some python basic tutorials. Indentation is an essential part of the python language. And if you don't understand what it does, you will never understand python code.

try this:

```
import bpy

text_file = open("C:\\Users\\nabuc\\Desktop\\1700txt - copia.txt", "r")
lines = []



#Read in contents to a list
for line in text_file:
    lines.append(line.strip())

#create spheres
for e in lines:
    temp=e.split(',')
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments = 64, ring_count = 32, location=(float(temp[0]),float(temp[1]),float(temp[2])),scale = (float(temp[3]),float(temp[3]),float(temp[3])))
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
text_file.close()
```

Comment: The same error appears  (I remove that 'tab' before last line)
"Python script failed, check the message in the system console"

Comment: ok, then copy some lines of your .txt here

Comment: 3.6105752578067E-4,4.57866439980116E-5,2.96020503639462E-4,3.8E-5
1.29135076069346E-4,1.70596056159248E-4,1.65624196671979E-4,3.8E-5
3.30313121806365E-4,1.01079824554117E-4,1.91925777727024E-4,3.8E-5
2.51591805391055E-4,1.11234635850882E-4,3.09032838060921E-4,3.8E-5
9.60652657019447E-5,8.72360800639832E-5,1.52661649244708E-4,3.8E-5
1.59171641186626E-4,2.9455844644739E-5,1.89453981357743E-5,3.8E-5
2.29775668450222E-4,4.72599828082211E-5,1.40603740903784E-4,3.8E-5
1.70195058529528E-4,1.8789687568838E-4,9.87256408236967E-5,3.8E-5

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Oh my god
This worked well!!
But the dimension is very little!! (microns)
Probably you save my life with my College work (This is just a start point).
Now I'm try to see the geometry and export it. 
Thank you so much

Comment: you are welcome. please check the checkmark left to my answer. thank you.

Comment: Do you know, why it create 2 big spheres?

Comment: ooops, sorry, forgot to delete this: lines = ["1,2,3,2","1,2,4,3"] ...this was for my testing. i updated my answer

Comment: I thought it was this line that was making the code work hahahaha
thank you very much again
And go back to studying programming, I studied C ++ a long time ago in a basic way, now I'm going to start python

Comment: Can you please check the checkmark left to my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm tried. But: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: The checkmark! Not the upvote!

Comment: How do you display the image once this has been done?