# Int property not displaying in my panel?

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I am new to writing UI for Blender (2.92) and I am having a really difficult time understanding what is going on. I would like to add a panel for integer input by the user. When I look at reference code snippets they don't make sense to me and copying these bits of code across also doesn't seem to work.

I would appreciate some help in this regard so I can figure out what I have to do here. The examples I have attached are some last desperate attempts to copy across work from other examples found on the web (marked as blue) + the panel I am working on with a blue dashed line showing where I would like to display a user input.

A description would be nice instead of a vague example. I actually want to understand what is happening.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel

from bpy.props import IntProperty

class SMG_PT_Buttons(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "SMG Naming Button"
    bl_category = "SMG"
    bl_idname = "smg.naming"


    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        bpy.types.Scene.my_use_x = bpy.props.IntProperty()

        # Button 1

        layout.label(text="Parent Object")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('smg.write_region', text = "Write Regions")

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, 'my_use_x')

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('smg.write_territory', text = "Write Territories")
```

[image: Panel I am working on]

Comment: To see any error feedback https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go  Declare the property `bpy.types.Foo.prop = BarProperty(...)` outside the draw method, is  most often seen in an addons `register` method.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui/57332?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#57332

Comment: Ok will comment since  the question was closed.  Answer gives a fix, Reasons behind:  If you look in console when viewing panel `AttributeError: pyrna_struct_meta_idprop_setattro() can't set in readonly state 'Scene.my_use_x'`  _ie_ you cannot set (or declare ID types properties  from within a draw method. `context.scene.my_use_x = 10` will throw the same error.   There is also a warning on running script `Warning: 'smg.naming' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix`  suggesting you leave out `bl_idname`,   defaulting to   the class name, which in this case follows the naming convention.

Answer (score 4):

Just declare your scene property in `register()` and remove it in `unregister()`:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.props import IntProperty

class SMG_PT_Buttons(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "SMG Naming Button"
    bl_category = "SMG"
    bl_idname = "smg.naming"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        layout.label(text="Parent Object")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('smg.write_region', text = "Write Regions")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, 'my_use_x')
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('smg.write_territory', text = "Write Territories")


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_use_x = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    bpy.utils.register_class(SMG_PT_Buttons)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SMG_PT_Buttons)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_use_x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

As for detailed explanation, I can't think of much to say - the scene is not inside the panel, so its properties live outside panels as well, that's all.

Comment: IMO place it in the register method to define the property when the addon is registered not when it is imported.

Answer (score 3):

**Look for errors.**

On running a script in blender always keep an eye on the system console

[Where does console output go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go)

After adding a call to register this class

```
bpy.utils.register_class(SMG_PT_Buttons)
```

a warning is printed.

```
register_class(...):
Warning: 'smg.naming' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix
```

Suggest you leave out `bl_idname`, defaulting to the class name, which in this case follows the naming convention. To find this registered class

```
bpy.types.SMG_PT_Buttons
```

names like `"smg.foobar"` are for operators --> `bpy.ops.smg.foobar(..)`  Another option is to

```
class SMGButtonsPanel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "SMG_PT_buttons"
    ...
```

if you prefer having your own class names,

**Draw methods are read only.**

You cannot declare or set an ID object property from within a draw method.

On viewing the panel

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text.003", line 17, in draw
AttributeError: pyrna_struct_meta_idprop_setattro() can't set in readonly state 'Scene.my_use_x'
```

hence as shown in other answer declare the property from within your `register` method.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.props import IntProperty

class SMG_PT_Buttons(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "SMG Naming Button"
    bl_category = "SMG"

    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
       
        # Button 1

        layout.label(text="Parent Object")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('smg.write_region', text = "Write Regions")

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, 'my_use_x')

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('smg.write_territory', text = "Write Territories")
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SMG_PT_Buttons)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_use_x = IntProperty()
  
  
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SMG_PT_Buttons)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_use_x
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Test via python console.**

If I have script above as blender textblock "Text.003" I can emulate importing and registering in the python console

```
>>> m = D.texts['Text.003'].as_module()
>>> m.register()
register_class(...):
Warning: 'smg.naming' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix
```

Whoops, forgot to take out the idname, edit go again

```
>>> m = D.texts['Text.003'].as_module()
>>> m.register()
>>> m.unregister()
>>>
```