# Blender 3.0 python script

Tags: python

I would like to run simple python such as

x=5
print(x)

Which is running in the console but where does the code in the text editor output to?
Where do *I go
If I placed this in the text editor do I go to file>save or text>save?
I am having problems saving script in the text editor.

Thanks
UPDATE
I don't seem to have Window->Toggle System Console  system
[image]

The python console window look like this but doesn't seem to have Toggle System Console
[image]
and also in the python console window
[image]
I presume this is the python console window
[image]
Simple python code
[image]

But not outputting in the Python console window.

Answer (score 4):

Text->Save will save the script you were coding in the text editor in the Scripting workspace.

And if you're looking for the output of a print statement with code you ran in the text editor, go to Window->Toggle System Console. The output is there.

Comment: I don't seem to have Window->Toggle System Console I've updated the question . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### What happens to the output:

If you enter the code into the *Python console* window, the output will appear in the console window:

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.9.2 (default, Mar  1 2021, 08:18:55) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Builtin Modules:       bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports:   from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data

>>> print(5)
5
>>>
```

If you enter the code into the text editor and use the 'run' button to execute it, the text will appear in the *System console* window.  How you access the text in the system console window depends on the OS you are using.  On Windows 10, Go to the Window menu and select *Toggle System Console*:

[image: Window menu showing Toggle System Console]

The text will appear in that window:

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\stupi\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\config\userpref.blend
5
```

for example.

### How to save the code:

If you want to keep the code in the blend file, then you don't have to do anything.  The code will be saved when you save the blend file.

If you want to store the code in a separate python file, then in the text editor go to the *Text* menu and select *Save* or *Save As*:

[image: text editor Text menu showing the save and save as options]

To save

Comment: I forgot to say i'm uing Linux,Ubuntu 21.10 Thanks

Comment: Then instead of using the Window menu to toggle the System console, you would start Blender on the command line in a terminal window.  The output would go to that terminal window. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go/119523#119523) for an example command line.

Comment: Hi Marty Fouts starting Blender from the command line sounds like a whole new problem. I see you get Toggle System Console I can't get that. See my original post for screenshots thanks

Comment: You can only get Toggle System Console on Windows systems. Starting from the command line in Linux isn't that hard.  Start a terminal window and then type a blender command as in the answer that several people have mentioned.

Comment: Ok II'll try that thanks

Comment: Eventually I installed from the commandline and the command blender works now to launch blender. Unfortunatwle I stilll can't see wiindow>toggle System Console. But I could see python output in the terminal usinf youtube video fhttps://youtu.be/7GEvkfcOGNM by CGPython. It works now thanks  for your hrlp.