# Slow playback and frame regression

Tags: video-sequence-editor

The playback isn't synced. Audio can not be heard. The frame cursor continously jumps back to already played frames.

[image]

[image]

Blender 2.79#5db8ac9 (2017-09-11 10:43)

**Things I had done with this file.**

- video editing in the sequencer
- executed script with [codemanx's addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5420/30849) to set keys on strips
- rendered
- animation node to display tc with text strip

**Things I tried to solve the playback**

- *Frame Dropping* instead of *AV-sync* > works, but I can't hear audio
- delete all strips and data blocks
- disabled all addons
- hide all but one area
- reopened Blender, reopened the file
- check Blender's playback capabilities in another file (works)

I have lots of editing in this file, which would be difficult to reproduce in a new file. That's why I need a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting my computer solves this. Even though playback seemed fine in all other files, the playback was restored in this file as well after rebooting my OS.